# DRAM Memory : How is data stored from the HDD to DRAM?

Tags: memory, hardware, dram

When storing data from HDD to DRAM, is one large data block (e.g., 8 bytes) stored in one chip? Or is it distributed among multiple chips in a DIMM? If it is distributed, how many bytes of consecutive data are stored in one chip?

Comment: You’ve not specified the hardware involved. If this is a follow on from your previous question, we can assume PC hardware and an x86 processor. With dram, there is a cost of admission,ie: to set up a read or write operation takes a few clocks. Once setup, you would try and read the whole memory line from all chips on your DIMM in order to get the best efficiency. This is called a ‘burst load’ and the line of data is copied into cache. To read/write individual bytes to the dram is very slow and generally avoided. So for your hd data, it may even be spread across two or more DIMMs.

Comment: Why do you care at all? It would help us help you if we know the background of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8 bytes, 64 bits, is not a large block, in fact it is likely the smallest possible block in your system.

Assuming a 64 or 72 bit dimm, with 8 parts, that is 8 bits wide per part.  So for each aligned 64 bit block of data, one byte per part. (parts historically are 8, 16, 32 bits wide, but if you look you will most often see 8 and 16 bit wide parts)

> how many bytes of consecutive data are stored in one chip?

One chip has only one width of consecutive data.  An eight bit wide part on a 64 bit dimm will have only one "consecutive" byte in one chip.

You should not assume then that every 8th byte, consecutively, is stored on that memory part.  It will be true for chunks of data of some power of two size, but more than one place in the system from your view of consecutive and where it lands in caches or dram, can be spread about the address space for that layer.

Assuming a 64 or 72 bit dimm, and that means the world is in units of 64 bit quantities by the time it gets to dram, the byte 0 lane can be assumed to go to the same part, but the addressing is not assumed to be "linear" through that part relative to the programmers (kernel, pcie, mmu) view of address space.

HDD is assumed to be spinning media, with an interface like sata which is serial.  Then a pcie controller (which is also serial).  On an x86 pc the pcie address space is mapped directly into the system address space, but that is not true for all platforms.  pcie provides multiple masters and mostly likely dma controllers so that shoves the data into the system which works its way toward dram.

solid state ultimately comes through pcie as well so spinning media or not it makes its way to dram the same way/path.  The ssd technology is evolving to try to improve size and speed (at the cost of storage quality, lots of edac bits, I would assume no chunk of data is actually stored without error, maybe they have improved it).

Caches do more than just provide a relatively fast sram to short circuit memory transactions.  But on the dram side also allow for all transactions to be in units of bus width to the dram controller.  no byte or 16 bit transactions, etc.  all the same width.

Assume that the specification for the dimm itself dominates the nature of the transactions not the individual parts populated on the dimm (64 bit wide dimm being 64 bit transactions independent of 8/16/32 bit wide parts).

They will swizzle addresses across the system, but assume not byte lanes.

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer I was looking for. @old_timer\

Answer (score 0):

Hard drives are block-based devices so you cannot access individual bytes. Depending on the device the block size will be on the order of 512 to 4096 bytes. That will be copied into RAM. If you only need 8 bytes you can ignore the rest of the block.

How that is arranged physically in memory depends on what memory you have. However, since the blocksize is larger than the cache line size, the block will probably end up spread across multiple memory channels. The 8 bytes you want are smaller than a cache line, so they will end up in a single channel. Channels can be anywhere from 1-16 physical chips, so you'd have to look that up for your computer.